# MERGE between 2 tables, one table with 10million rows

Tags: sql-server, join, merge, exists

**TableA**
**match**      /     **Keyword**
0 Stackoverflow
1 **You**tube
1 **Go**ogle
0 Yandex
1 **Twit**ter
0 Facebook
0 Teac<strike>her</strike>
*Totally 10million rows in TableA*
*There is Clustered index at Keyword column*

**TableB**
**match**      /     **word**
1 **You**
1 **Go**
1 **Twit**
0 Home
0 Car
0 Pencil
0 Money
0 Weather
0 Her
*Totally 500 rows in TableB*
*There is Clustered index at word column*

**My Question**
i want to make a sql query to match every **word** from TableB if matches in TableA **keyword**s. And update the **TableB.match** with **1**
(TableA.keyword like '+TableB.word+'**%**') (*will be matched*)

NOT the middle of the keyword matches;  (TableA.keyword like '**%**'+TableB.word+'**%**')
Forexample **Her** -> in Teac**her** (*wont be matched*)

**I Tried to use MERGE**

**First Try;**
i tried to match keywords with words and update TableB
**i get error**, because there is multiple matches in TableA and MERGE do not allow updating multiple times a row in Target table (TableB)

```
MERGE INTO [TableB] As XB 
USING (Select keyword FROM [TableA]) As XA 
ON XB.word LIKE ''+XA.keyword+'%' 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET XB.match=1;
```

**Second Try;**
i tried to match words with keywords and update TableA
**i get what i want**, The problem is, it takes **1 hour** to execute the query for 500words in 10million keywords.

```
MERGE INTO [TableA] As XA 
USING (Select word FROM [TableB]) As XB 
ON XB.word LIKE ''+XA.keyword+'%' 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET XA.match=1;
```

Is there an option to fasten these lookups in **SecondTry**?

Comment: Why are you using a merge here? It seems that you are only doing something when matched. This should be an update statement. And no matter how you slice this the performance is going to be horrible. You are doing wildcard searches looking for the existence of any of 500 words in 10 million rows. Indexing is not going to help here at all.

Comment: So, if a word from table B appears anywhere in table a, you want it to have match = 1, otherwise 0?

Comment: and the word from table b MUST be at the beginning of table a?

Comment: do you also want match = 1 in table a if there's a match?

Comment: Yes, anywhere in the begining position of the keyword column in TableA. And update TableB.match column to 1. No, i do not want to update TableA,  THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An update statement will suffice for what you're trying to do.  Note that this will probably not perform very well as SQL isn't great at comparing strings.

```
declare @a table (match int, keyword varchar(50))
declare @b table (match int, keyword varchar(50))

insert into @a values (0, 'Stackoverflow')
insert into @a values (0, 'Youtube')
insert into @a values (0, 'Google')
insert into @a values (0, 'Yandex')
insert into @a values (0, 'Twitter')
insert into @a values (0, 'Facebook')
insert into @a values (0, 'Teacher')


insert into @b values (0, 'You')
insert into @b values (0, 'Go')
insert into @b values (0, 'Twit')
insert into @b values (0, 'Home')
insert into @b values (0, 'Car')
insert into @b values (0, 'Pencil')
insert into @b values (0, 'Money')
insert into @b values (0, 'Weather')
insert into @b values (0, 'Her')

--commented out because user didn't want this, but it matches the provided data
--update @a
--set match = 1
--where keyword in
--(
--  select 
--      distinct a.keyword
--  from @a a
--  cross apply @b b
--  where a.keyword like b.keyword + '%'
--)

update @b
set match = 1
where keyword in
(
    select 
        distinct b.keyword
    from @a a
    cross apply @b b
    where a.keyword like b.keyword + '%'
)

select *
from @a

select *
from @b
```

--EDIT BY Sean--
Here is how you could do this as a correlated subquery so you can use EXISTS.

```
update b
set match = 1
from @b b
where exists
(
    select b.keyword
    from @a a
    where a.keyword like b.keyword + '%'
)
```

Comment: Changing "where keyword in" to "where exists" would help performance here.

Comment: @SeanLange hmm, I tried that and it marks everything as 1

Comment: Ohh....I see. You need to make it a correlated subquery. I will show you how here in a bit.

Comment: interesting.  I'm a bit unsure as to whether it would make much of a difference since b is the smaller table.  the real hang up is comparing a.keyword to b.keyword

Comment: Agreed. There is no code that is going to make this anything other than stupidly slow with 10 million rows.

Comment: DForck42 Thanks and @SeanLange Your code helpmed me to execute my query in 4-5 seconds instead of an hour with MERGE +1 Thanks

Comment: @G.KISA if this code worked for you then you should consider marking this as the accepted answer.